# JSON.NET Silverlight SerializeXmlNode

Tags: silverlight, json, json.net

I couldn't find serializexmlnode method in JSON.NET's Silverlight dll.Is it exist in SL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't - XmlDocument, XmlElement, XmlNode, etc aren't available in Silverlight.

The latest version of Json.NET does have SerializeXNode however for the LINQ to XML objects.